# Jquery not selecting closest div after post

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem which has been bugging me for a day now, perhaps you can help me.
See below code:

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body">
<div class"in-between header">
</div>
<div class="well well-lg">
<div class="readmore">
</div>
</div>
<div class="knoppen">
<span id="editconfirm" style="font-size: 80%;"></span>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="edit">Edit</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.edit').on('click',function(){

var m = $(this).closest('.panel-body').find('.well-lg').attr('msgid');

$(this).closest('.panel-body').find('.well-lg').attr('contenteditable','true');
$(this).closest('.panel-body').find('.well-lg').css("background-color", "#fff");
$(this).closest('.panel-body').find('.well-lg').css("border", "solid 1px #ccc");
$(this).closest('.panel-body').find('.well-lg').css("outline-style", "none");
$(this).closest('.panel-body').find('#stop').css("display", "block").hide().fadeIn("slow");
$(this).closest('.panel-body').find('#bewaar').css("display", "block").hide().fadeIn("slow");
$(this).closest('.panel-body').find('#editconfirm').html("Note: click on <strong>read more</strong> before editing large posts. " + m).hide().fadeIn("slow");

$.post("editmsg.php",
        {
          m: m
        },
        function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
$(this).closest('.panel-body').find('.well-lg').html(data);
    });
});
```

What I want to happen is that when a user decides to edit their post, the text to edit gets fetched from the data base and replaces the text visible. This is because of the presence of smileys, which are character combinations which upon load get replaced by images of smileys. Since I can only have them edit text, the image would get removed and the character combi would not be saved in the database. Loss of smileys is a consequence of that.

What happens with this code is that it does make the correct div editable and everything else that needs to be done. The only thing that does NOT happen is that the text currently visible gets replaced by editable text (so including the char combi which upon load is being replaced back to a smiley).

The `.closest().find()` formula finds the desired div perfectly, but after the `funtion(data,status)` formula, it doesn't seem to find it anymore. The `$.post` statement works as the alert shows me the correct data to be pulled off the db, including char combi and all. I tried `.prev()`, `prevAll(divname)`, `.parent().child()`, `parent().children()`, it doesn't seem to like any of those after the post statement and frankly it's driving me nuts by now.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you and if something is not clear, just say so :)

Comment: You have to store `$(this).closest('.panel-body')` before your function because `this` in function is the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
$('.edit').on('click',function(){

    var panelbody = jQuery(this).closest('.panel-body') ;

    var m = panelbody.find('.well-lg').attr('msgid');

    panelbody.find('.well-lg').attr('contenteditable','true');
    panelbody.find('.well-lg').css("background-color", "#fff");
    panelbody.find('.well-lg').css("border", "solid 1px #ccc");
    panelbody.find('.well-lg').css("outline-style", "none");
    panelbody.find('#stop').css("display", "block").hide().fadeIn("slow");
    panelbody.find('#bewaar').css("display", "block").hide().fadeIn("slow");
    panelbody.find('#editconfirm').html("Note: click on <strong>read more</strong> before editing large posts. " + m).hide().fadeIn("slow");

    $.post(
        "editmsg.php",
        {m: m},
    function(data,status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        panelbody.find('.well-lg').html(data);
    });
});
```

I'm not sure what you want to do but in your code, $(this) in the function(data...) does not refer to previous $(this), because it's in the function context.

If you want to have the same thing, save your `jQuery(this).closest('.panel-body')` in a var, so you will be abled to re-use it after post data.

Comment: This did the trick :) Thank you very much! The idea is that when users want to edit their post with smileys, to have the text they see replaced with the one that's stored in the db. Smileys as shown on the page are actually images and therefore will disappear once editing has been done as it won't save the image as such. Instead a smiley gets saved as a character combination which gets replaced by a corresponding image. Hope this makes it a little more clear :) Thanks a million for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the scope of $.post, and the success function, `this` means something different. It contains the entire ajax object, not the element clicked.

Store the value for `this` in the outer scope, and use the variable in the inner. To make all that DOM-searching a bit easier, I suggest you make a few variables to hold your different elements:

```
$('.edit').on('click', function () {
  var clicked = $(this);
  var panelBody = clicked.closest('.panel-body');
  var wellLg = panelBody.find('.well-lg');

  var m = wellLg.attr('msgid');

  wellLg.attr('contenteditable','true');
  wellLg.css("background-color", "#fff");
  wellLg.css("border", "solid 1px #ccc");
  wellLg.css("outline-style", "none");
  panelBody.find('#stop').css("display", "block").hide().fadeIn("slow");
  panelBody.find('#bewaar').css("display", "block").hide().fadeIn("slow");
  panelBody.find('#editconfirm').html("Note: click on <strong>read more</strong> before editing large posts. " + m).hide().fadeIn("slow");

  $.post("editmsg.php", { m: m }, function(data,status) {
    wellLg.html('This is the response. It Works fine!');
    //wellLg.html(data);
  });
});
```

Snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/ejnqa2Ly/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift answer. Unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: I see you already accepted an answer while I was saving the fiddle. Good for you. You can confirm that my code was also working by checking the link in my answer, or not .. you have your answer :)

Comment: Thank you again for your efforts - I am really happy this got resolved as it was doing my head in. I would like to give you both points for your efforts, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation yet to do so. I hope my sincere gratefulness will do :) Cheers from Ireland!